# Why is my SQLite Database not created/saved to disk?

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio, android-sqlite, virtualization, sqliteopenhelper

I created code to create a SQLite database based on the article [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial).

The most pertinent code is:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Platypus.db";
private static final String TABLE_VENDORS = "vendors";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_VENDORID = "vendorId";
public static final String COLUMN_COMPANYNAME = "companyName";

public SQLiteHandlerVendors(Context context, String vendor,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int company) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_VENDORS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_VENDORS + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_VENDORID
            + " TEXT," + COLUMN_COMPANYNAME + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_VENDORS_TABLE);
}

public void addVendor(Vendor vendor) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_VENDORID, vendor.getVendorId());
    values.put(COLUMN_COMPANYNAME, vendor.getCompanyName());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert(TABLE_VENDORS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Yet, although the insertions of data seem to be working -- the calls to `addVendor()` run without any exception being thrown with the following code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            String vendorId = jsonObj.getString("vendorId");
            String companyName = jsonObj.getString("companyName");
            Log.i("vendorId", vendorId);
            Log.i("companyName", companyName);
            // Prepare for writing to db
            Vendor vend = new Vendor();
            vend.setVendorId(vendorId);
            vend.setCompanyName(companyName);
            SQLiteHandlerVendors sqliteHandler = new SQLiteHandlerVendors(MainActivity.this, null, null, 1);
            sqliteHandler.addVendor(vend);
        }
    } catch (JSONException j) {
        System.out.println(j.getMessage());
        Log.i("jsonEx", j.getMessage());
    }
    Log.i("GetVendorsTask.FromOnPostExecute", result);
}
```

I cannot locate the *Platypus.db* file that should have been created.

[This article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) says, "*If your application creates a database, this database is by default saved in the directory DATA/data/APP_NAME/databases/FILENAME*."

A global search for "Platypus.DB" on my hard drive turns up nothing. Is the database created not being persisted, or is there some other reason why I'm not finding it?

I tried to find it by adding this code:

```
Log.i("Data Dir", Environment.getDataDirectory().toString());
```

...and when LogCat gives me is:

```
04-07 12:36:47.133    1089-1089/platypus.app I/Data Dir﹕ /data
```

There is no "data" folder in *C:\Users\clay\AndroidStudioProjects\Platypus*, nor is there one in the root of my hard drive (*C:*).

Can the data dir/file only be viewed in some virtual space, in a file system for the emulator or so? If so, how can I actually access the emulator's file system to view this data?

### UPDATE

Okay, I opened up this view, and navigated to data/data/hhs (the app's name is really "hhs" not "platypus"):

[image]

...but still do not see HHS.DB (I see no "databases" folder below all that)...

### UPDATE 2

If I select the "<=" button ("Pull a file from the device") with the file with the size of 16384 highlighted, it *does* open the "Get Device File" dialog with a filename of "HHS.DB" (just what I was hoping to find).

But, why is its path "data\data\hhs\unnamed folder\unnamed file" instead of "data\data\hhs\databases\HHS.DB"?

The other file (size 8720) is HHS.db-journal

### UPDATE 3

After saving those files to my hard drive and downloading [SQLite Data Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/), I'm able to verify that the records actually were written to the table:

[image]

SQLite Data Browser is a great tool for just such a need!

### UPDATE 4

I don't know what changed/how it changed, but it's now working as it should:

[image]

Comment: You are assumption is wrong. Its created on your phone. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getDataDirectory(). You are looking at the wrong place for your db. `/data/data/[packagename]/databases/`

Comment: Okay, so how can I see it? I'm not using an actual device, but an emulator. Is there a tool that allows me to see what is on the emulator. Or, since the emulator is a "fakeroo," does the table not exist at all, even in a mocked-up sort of way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no "data" folder in
>   C:\Users\clay\AndroidStudioProjects\Platypus, nor is there one in the
>   root of my hard drive (*C:*).

Yes that is corect.

> Can the data dir/file only be viewed in some virtual space, in a file
>   system for the emulator or so? If so, how can I actually access the
>   emulator's file system to view this data?

Using Eclipse you can pull the db from your emulator

Goto windows open perspective. Goto DDMS

Then goto file explorer-> data->data->see your package name-> databases->Platypus.DB"

```
/data/data/[packagename]/databases/
```

You select the db and there is a option to pull the db and then you can use a sqlite browser to view the data

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse, I'm using Droidio (Android Studio). I'll see if it's an analogous location...

Comment: @B.ClayShannon you can still use DDMS there also. Check this http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html